# How do I use a previous word in my snippet?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I'm coding a lot in `go` these days and one pattern I use often is iterating over slices and would like to use a snippet for this. There are generic for loop snippets that work well, but I'd like to take it a step forward.

The below is my expected behavior of the snippet:

Imagine there's a slice (could be an array/list in other languages) of name `apples`. Now when i type `apples.iter` followed by the expand trigger(Tab in my config) it should expand to the following:

```
for _, apple := range apples {

}
```

stripping the `s` from the list name is doable using python interpolation. But, I'm not sure on what should be set as the snippet expand word when defining my custom snippet.

My little research makes me believe, some kind of regular expression could be used, but didn't find any useful examples yet.

Can this be done, using `ultisnips`?

I know we could always use a regular snippet, expand and then type `apples`. But the `.iter` would feel more natural (at least to me) and can be extended to other use-cases like `.isnull`, `.isempty` etc.

P.S: I'm on the latest version of `vim` and `ultisnips`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
snippet '(\b\w+\b)\.iter' "loop list" r
for _, ${1:`!p snip.rv = match.group(1)[:-1]`} := range `!p snip.rv = match.group(1)` {
    ${0}
}
endsnippet
```

Add trailing `r` to use regular expression style trigger_word. `(\b\w+\b)\.iter` matches `apples.iter`. `match` is returned value of the match of the regular expression. `match.group(1)` is list name.

- `:h UltiSnips-python`

Comment: Thank you, that works really well!

Comment: I was trying to make this work and was close. This topic is covered in this video: https://www.sirver.net//blog/2012/03/31/fourth-episode-of-ultisnips-screencast/